# python function that mimics a web search

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a python function that mimics a web search. For example, I have three websites and keywords that correspond to the websites. The function should return the set of all the webpages that all the words appear on. I have turned the webpages and keywords into strings by doing this and creating a set of tuples:

```
d = {("www.page0.com", {"dog", "cat", "fish"}),("www.page1.com", {"cat", "rat", "frog", "dog"}), ("www.page2.com", {"cat", "rat", "fish", "goat"})}
```

Now, I need to write a function that creates and returns a dictionary that maps words to pages.  Thus, the keys will be the word strings and the values will be sets of pages where that word appears. So for our example above, 2 of the dictionary entries would be:

```
"cat": {"www.page0.com", "www.page1.com", "www.page2.com"}
"goat": {"www.page2.com")
```

I've created the function:

```
def createPageDict(d):
    return dict((v(x), y) for v in d)      
createPageDict(d)
```

Comment: Great. You have a task. You have a solution. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def create_dict(d):
    ret = defaultdict(set)
    for site, vals in d:
        for v in vals:
            ret[v].add(site)
    return ret

pages = create_dict(d)
for i, j in pages.items():
    print(i, j)
```

Gives:

```
dog {'www.page0.com', 'www.page1.com'}
cat {'www.page0.com', 'www.page2.com', 'www.page1.com'}
fish {'www.page0.com', 'www.page2.com'}
rat {'www.page2.com', 'www.page1.com'}
frog {'www.page1.com'}
goat {'www.page2.com'}
```

Note that I turned your `d` into

```
d = (("www.page0.com", ("dog", "cat", "fish")),("www.page1.com", ("cat", "rat", "frog", "dog")), ("www.page2.com", ("cat", "rat", "fish", "goat")))
```

because `sets` are an unhashable type, so your `d` literal was incorrect.

If you don't want to use `defaultdict`, you just have to check if the key is in your dictionary before adding to the set:

```
def create_dict(d):
    ret = {}
    for site, vals in d:
        for v in vals:
            if v in ret:
                ret[v].add(site)
            else:
                ret[v] = {site}
    return ret
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! how do i get around not using defaultdict? we haven't been taught that yet.

Comment: @JOE No problem! Added another solution.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help